# Contains does not show proper info

Tags: java, groovy

I keep trying to make this piece of code work.
I know it is very simple but for some reason it does not work, neither with matches or contains. It always go to "It does not work"

```
  def var="pst-dhn-publisher1.prg-dc.dada.com"
    
    
            if (var.contains("pen|pst|uat1|uat2|uat3|test")) {
             println "works"
            }
            else {
            
                  println "It does not work"
            }
```

Why is that?

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this piece of code?

Comment: if it contains "pen" > do something , if it contains "pst" do something else and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contains is whole string match

is this what u are looking for ?

```
def var="pst-dhn-publisher1.prg-dc.dada.com"
    
    
            if (var =~ ("com|pst|uat1|uat2|uat3|test")) {
               println "works"
            }
            else {
            
                  println "It does not work"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use matches, like this:

```
def var="pst-dhn-publisher1.prg-dc.dada.com"
if (var.matches(".*pen.*|.*pst.*|.*uat1.*|.*uat2.*|.*uat3.*|.*test.*")) 
{
   println "works"
}
else 
{
   println "It does not work"
}
```